# how to have a proper java key bindings code?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am working on a little game and using key bindings.
In my game i have a main JPanel containing all the bindings i want since all keys should be available at any time. After reading some examples I have this working code :

```
    KeyStroke endTurnKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2");
    mainPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(endTurnKey, "endTurnAction");
    mainPanel.getActionMap().put("endTurnAction", new EndTurn(this));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        KeyStroke selectSpell = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(49 + i, 0);
        mainPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(selectSpell, "selectSpell" + i);
        mainPanel.getActionMap().put("selectSpell" + i, new SelectSpell(this, i));
    }
```

And my SelectSpell class is :

```
public class SelectSpell extends AbstractAction {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private World w;
private int spellIndex;

public SelectSpell(World w, int spellIndex) {
    this.w = w;
    this.spellIndex = spellIndex;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // Whatever depending on spellIndex
}
}
```

What i want is a class or something i could name "Bindings" with a succession of "this key does this, this one does this, ..." in order to change them easily, add new ones...
I also find my AbstractAction herited class a bit ... wrong in some point, is it normal to use a local variable to specify what to do in actionPerformed ? An other problem is i have to create a new class for each type of action, is it normal ?

Comment: *is it normal to use a local variable to specify what to do in actionPerformed ?* - yes. This is an easy way to reuse similar Action. For example up/down/left/right. The local variable might be the x/y offset. Then you create different instances of the same class, but with different parameters. For an example of this approach take a look at the `MotionWithKeyBindings` class found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

Comment: *An other problem is i have to create a new class for each type of action, is it normal ?* - each Action does something different, so yes you want to create a different class or instance of a class.